# How to modify the Webhook Step Plugin in Jenkins to meet my pipeline needs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I Currently have a Pipeline built in Jenkins to run my newman Test Cases. So the definition for it is in three steps

1. Call the Async Test cases.
2. Register a Webhook and Wait for it to respond back to continue forward.
3. Call the remaining Test cases.

I'm using the existing "Webhook Step Plugin" to register and wait for my Webhook in Jenkins.

Definition:

[Pipeline Definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hcz5N.png)

**Problem:**

This resgisterWebhook() method is returning a random URL everytime because it is using the UUID logic to generate a random token. And since its random everytime, my external System cannot know it.

**Question:**

So i'm looking for a way, where the hook URL will be constant always, so that it can be hardcoded in my external System and called once the Async Operation is completed.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the webhook step, either use the webhook trigger plugin, or use the generic webhook trigger inside pipeline.  (these may be the same thing - I may have just stuttered.  Sorry if so!).

Anyway, that lets you set up a static URL you can use to trigger builds.